# membership change password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, passwords, membership

how can i change password manual directly in table membership? passwordformat=1, so how can i crypt password before insert into table?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change the password using the .NET API? That would make the encryption much easier.

Comment: in api i need to give users old password but i want to change password by main admin so it don't need to pass old user password. (if passwords encrypt it not allow to call retreivepassword)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a hack you can use:

Assuming you're not *requiring* the Security Question / Answer feature, you can call the `ResetPassword()` method in the membership API and then use the return value of that method as the old value for `ChangePassword()`.

Something like this:

```
 Membership.GetUser().ChangePassword(Membership.GetUser().ResetPassword(), "new password");
```

There's a [more complicated hack](http://peterkellner.net/2007/02/15/resetpasswordaspnet/) you can use if you are *requiring* the Security Q&A.